# unable to bind value to ng-model of select with ng-repeat on button click

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have TableObject as below

```
$scope.tableObject = [
    {
        'Column_Name' : 'Dummy 1',
        'Column_Cliass' : 'Valid'
    },
    {
        'Column_Name' : 'Dummy 2',
        'Column_Cliass' : 'Invalid'
    }
]
```

Now plotting select control using ng-repeat as below.

```
<div class="row networkDataBR" ng-repeat="lTable in tableObject">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="lookupFile" ng-options="option as option.name for option in onlyFiles">
    </select>   
</div>
```

It will make two Select Controls, Now on Button Click I want to assign value to one select control from Controller.

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="appendFile("Network")" value="Append" />

$scope.appendFile = function(dataValue) {
    _.each($scope.tableObject, function (lTable) {
        if (lTable.Column_Name === "dummy") {
            $scope.lookupFile = dataValue;
        }
    });
};
```

However, it applies to both the select control. So how to apply to single select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using same model variable for both select controls. Use different variable something like this

```
<div class="row networkDataBR" ng-repeat="lTable in tableObject">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="lookupFile[$index]" ng-options="option as option.name for option in onlyFiles">
    </select>   
</div>

<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="appendFile("Network",0)" value="Append" />


$scope.lookupFile={};
    $scope.appendFile = function(dataValue,index) {
        _.each($scope.tableObject, function (lTable) {
            if (lTable.Column_Name === "dummy") {
                $scope.lookupFile[index] = dataValue;
            }
        });
    };
```